# react-native why I get memory leak if I use this useEffect method

Tags: react-native, expo

why I get memomy leak if I use this code:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if(step === 2) {
      BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', () => handleStep1WithBackhandler());
      return () => {
        BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', () => handleStep1WithBackhandler());
      }
    } else {
        if(hardware === true) {
        BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', () => false);
        return () => {
          BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', () => false);
        }
      } 
    }
  }, [step]);
```

if step is equal to 2 then I go back to step1 with the function. Else nothing.

Whats wrong with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be due to arrow functions in addEventListener and removeEventListener
In addition to the value of the step within the eventListener you can use this approach:

Create a customHook for tracking a state to a ref.

```
const useStateRef = (defaultValue = null)=> {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(defaulValue)
  
  const ref = useRef()
  
  useEffect(()=> {
    ref.current = value
  },[value])
  
  return  [value, setValue, ref]
}
```

and use it as follows

```
const SomeComponent = () => {
  const [step, setStep, stepRef] = useStateRef(1)
  const handleBackPress = React.useCallBack(() => {
    if (stepRef.current === 2) {
    //some logic
    }
    if (someWhere.hardware) {
     //some logic
    }
  },[])
  
  useEffect(()=> {
   BackHandler.addEventListener('hadwareBackPress',handleBackPress)
   
   return ()=> BackHandler.removeEventListener('hadwareBackPress',handleBackPress)
  },[])


  //some code ... 

  //return something ...

  return null

}
```